# Refreshing cookies every time when login using python requests library

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, refresh

I am just trying to login a site , but the problem is the cookie used by the site has a token in it , so i need to refresh the cookie every time .
Is there any way to refresh cookies in python requests library?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you created a requests session as

```
s = requests.session()
```

To clear the cookies for this session you would add:

```
s.cookies.clear()
```

Comment: Got it .But is there any ways i can get the cookie without sending any request to the url ?

Comment: If the cookies are static, then you could go into google chrome and use edit this cookie and put them as a dict in your program. Im not sure if this answers your question so feel free to clarify.